# Delete a character from a file in C

Tags: c

How can I delete few characters from a file using C program?

I could not find any predefined functions for it.

To understand the purpose, I am trying to send a file through a socket, if N bytes are sent successfully, I want to delete those bytes from the file. At the end, the file will be empty.
Any other way to do this efficiently?

Thanks
Pradeep

Answer (score 4):

If they're at the end, truncate the file at the appropriate length. If they're not then you'll need to rewrite the file.

Comment: Although be aware that standard C doesn't have a function to truncate a file (other than to 0 length). POSIX does, as does Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Your way is pretty inefficient for large files, since you would have to copy "the rest of the file" some bytes further to the beginning, which costs much. I would rather record the "current sending position" somewhere outside of the file and update that information. That way, you don't have to copy the rest of the file so often.

Comment: I was thinking the same, but, what if the client(which is sending the file) crashes?

Comment: What if the power is cut before hard disk buffers are flushed?  Same problem.  What if the power is cut while you are deleting the bytes from the beginning of the file?  The file data gets corrupted.  You are better off asking the server you are sending to how many bytes it received and send from that point on.

Comment: @Blacklabel: you should sync the "current position" from time to time. And maybe the client should include the desired position into the request (like HTTP Content-Range/206)

Comment: you can use a hand shaking method at the beginning of the connection that client and server tells each other how many bytes server have received and how many byte client have sent, then you should take the minimum of these values as the size of data that transmitted and start sending rest of your data.

Comment: @HPT: The number of bytes the server has received should never be greater than the number the client has sent.  The server should always know how many bytes it needs; just take the server value.

Comment: Ok, things are little complex here. The server will upload the received data into a SQL database and forgets it :) So the server doesnt know how many bytes it read from client. It is the purpose of the client to send the data reliably surviving all kind of crashes :)

Comment: @cdhowie: assume that server has some delay in saving received data, then client has sent some bytes and server received them but hadn't saved them for example in hard disk or maybe processing them and then server crashes, so number of byte sent by client is bigger than number of bytes server have processed, as the matter of data transferring you are right but if server receives data and then do something on them and then mark them as completed data it can happen

Comment: @HPT: That will still not result in the server having a larger number of bytes received than the client.

Comment: @HPT. Good point. I have to write an application level Acknowledgement now :)

Comment: @Blacklabel: The client cannot possibly know this information.  It's possible that the network connection timed out, for example, after the client sent some data.  The server will never receive it, but the client will have marked it sent.  The client and server need some way to coordinate with each other; recording data just on the client is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: @cdhowie: I am taking care of that. I increase at the client end only if the buffers are flushed successfully by TCP. This means the data is sent successfully to server, if the server crashes now before uploading the data to the database, it is server's problem. I will take care of that.

Comment: @HPT: How can I save the value as a registry value? Wont that value will be flushed if the program crashes?

Comment: @Blacklabel: Do a search on MSDN for the following functions;
CreateRegKeyEx() / RegSetValueEx() / RegCloseKey()

Answer (score 1):

There is no straightforward way to delete bytes from the beginning of a file.  You will have to start from where you want to trim the file, and read from there to the end of the file, writing to the start of the file.

It might make more sense to just track how many bytes you have already written to the file in some other file.

Answer (score 1):

you should use an index which points to the beginning of the data you haven't sent yet.
It is not necessary to delete what you have sent, just pass them, when you send the whole file delete it.

Answer (score 0):

If the char's are one after the other than why dont you give a try to **fseek();**